# Partially differentiate a function in R using the 'Deriv' package

Tags: r, symbolic-math, differentiation

I need to write a function in R which depends on a vector x (which changes with every simulation) and has parameters beta_0, beta_1, beta_2. I'm trying to find the partial derivative of this function with respect to beta_0, beta_1 and beta_2.
I have written a code for the same but its repeatedly returning errors.

My R code is as follows:

```
func_1 <- function(x,beta_0,beta_1,beta_2){
  
  k <- beta_0+(x[1]*beta_1)+(x[2]*beta_2)
  k <- exp(k)/(1+exp(k))
  
}
Deriv(func_1(x=c(2,3)), 'beta_0')
```

The following error is being returned:

```
Error in func_1(x = c(2, 3)) : 
  argument "beta_0" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In Deriv(func_1(x = c(2, 3)), "beta_0") :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

Comment: Oops. Yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the partial derivative with respect to `beta_0` you still need to specify values for all of the parameters. You also need to pass `Deriv` a *function* (or an expression); in your example you're trying to *evaluate* the function at `x=c(2,3)` (without specifying values of the other arguments/parameters). In other words, if you have a function `foo` you need to pass `foo`, not `foo([something])`. So for example:

```r
library(Deriv)
dd <- Deriv(func_1, "beta_0")
dd(x=c(2,3), beta_0 = 1, beta_1 = 1, beta_2 =1)
##      beta_0 
## 0.002466509
```

Here `dd` is the partial derivative with respect to `beta_0`, which is a function that can be evaluated at any numerical values you like. (if you need a *symbolic* partial derivative - i.e.. the value for arbitrary values of `beta_0`, `beta_1`, `beta_2` - I'm not sure that `Deriv` will do that ...)

Comment: The help page for `Deriv` says it can handle either a function or an expression and then it demonstrates both in the examples.

Comment: @IRTFM, I'm not sure how to respond to your comment; I tried to clarify my answer, but I might have missed your point.

Comment: You got my point. I was concerned that you had only mentioned 'function' as the class of the first argument.